# Rails Koala gem - facebook publish_stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

As facebook remove publish_stream from API, what is other way to put post on wall for user who register by facebook on site?

```
scope => "email, publish_stream"
```

This doesn't work, and I don't have permission to put something on user wall because facebook remove this option.

Answer (score 0):

The public_stream permission is present under the "Extended Permissions". 
Got to this link
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Click on "Get Access Token", in the pop up we have two options "User Data Permissions" and "Extended Permissions".

Under "Extended Permission" check the check box "Public_actions". This will set the permission to post the message on walls.

EG:

graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(ACCESS_TOKEN)
graph.put_connections("me", "feed", :message => "I am writing on my wall!")

Comment: no, it doesn't work, I have no permissions for publish_actions

Comment: In the graph explorer have enabled the permission for your app?

Comment: Yes I have ... publish_stream and publish_actions are removed from API for other applications. I search for something like auto share after login or something like that.